# Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days don't work properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I have been visiting this SE SO website over a month now but still didn't get this silver badge, I looked at calender and it shows I have been visiting this website on Monday - Friday basis.

I guess the issue is, I have been visiting this site from work on weekdays and then on weekends I visited it from my home, but it didn't counted them.

Did anyone else had same issues ?

Comment: yah I have exactly same issue as yours.
I think they are managing record with respect to our unique IP address so that our consecutive day are not counted when we login from other PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, dates and days are based on [UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it) and so days [starts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start).

Additionally, you need [to do something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)(answer, ask, vote, comment, review, ...) to get bagde for having an uptime(scroll down/ search for fanatic badge).

Comment: I was going for this one once until I missed the login cutoff because of the timezone difference. It is based on UTC. However I'm not sure that's an issue for @TimeToThine seeing as how he is on GMT.

Comment: @rjcup3 That is why I linked my words `to do someting` and how to find what there.

Comment: How does my comment have anything to do with activity? I was talking about time zones... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone

Comment: As far as I read it, the Questioner is asking about visiting consecutivly SE-sites. One point is which time zone is relavant - the other point is the activity. Because the refered badges only appear, if you do something valueable for each SE site you want to the badge.